# Is there an upload limit on Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I can't seem to upload files more than 5mb in firebase storage using firebase function with busboy. the error returns:

> ResumableUploadError: A resumable upload could not be performed. The
>   directory, /tmp/.config, is not writable. You may try another upload,
>   this time setting `options.resumable` to `false`.

Less than 5mb works. is there a work around if 5mb is the limit?

EDIT:

Here is my code

```
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  const admin = require('firebase-admin');
  const express = require('express');

  var serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json');
  admin.initializeApp(
  {credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL:dbURL})
  let gcs = admin.storage();
  const bucketName = 'bucket name';

  const app = express();
  const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

  app.post('/addImage',(req,res)=>{

    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    let uploadData = null;
    let origFileName;

    busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
      origFileName = filename
      const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filename);
      uploadData = { file: filepath, type: mimetype };
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
    });

    let formData = new Map();
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
      formData.set(fieldname, val);
    });

    busboy.on("finish", () => {
      const bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);
      let uuid = UUID();
      let dataURL = ''
      let company = formData.get('company');
      let eventCode = formData.get('eventCode');
      let type = formData.get('type');
      bucket
        .upload(uploadData.file, {
          uploadType: "media",
          metadata: {
            metadata: {
              contentType: uploadData.type,
              firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
            }
          },
          destination: company+"/"+eventCode+"/"+type+"/"+origFileName
        }).then(data=>{

          let file = data[0];
          dataURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" + bucket.name + "/o/" + encodeURIComponent(file.name) + "?alt=media&token=" + uuid;


          return res.status(200).send(result);
        })
        .catch(error =>{
          console.log("error",error)
          if (err) return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
        })

    });
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
  })
```

Comment: I'm aware of no such limits.  Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: maybe it's only permission problem, try sudo chmod 777  /tmp/.config, remember 777 is for testing only, if success then change it as needed..

Comment: @DougStevenson added my code for uploading

Comment: Thanks.  That doesn't look like a complete Cloud Functions trigger.  Could you show the entire function?

Comment: @DougStevenson here's everything

Comment: What exactly are you sending to the function?  Please be specific about how this function is being triggered.  Optimally, there is enough information for anyone to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Also please take a look at the code in the documentation and see how what you're doing is different than what's recommended (especially the use of promises to wait for streams to complete): https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you require for your use case to have `options.resumable=true`? If that doesn't break your use case switch it to false and it should work for you.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/File#createWriteStream) you have more information about `createWriteStream`.

> Resumable uploads are automatically enabled and must be shut off explicitly by setting options.resumable to false.
>
> Resumable uploads require write access to the $HOME directory. Through config-store, some metadata is stored. By default, if the directory is not writable, we will fall back to a simple upload. However, if you explicitly request a resumable upload, and we cannot write to the config directory, we will return a ResumableUploadError.
>
> There is some overhead when using a resumable upload that can cause noticeable performance degradation while uploading a series of small files. When uploading files less than 10MB, it is recommended that the resumable feature is disabled.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

It comes by default as enabled, you have to pass it as an option set to false in createWriteStream, try to do that and see if it allows you to upload.

For example like this.

You would have to pass it your filepath as you do and then add the option of resumable.

```
.createWriteStream({
          resumable: false,
          metadata: {
            contentType: 'text/plain',
          },
        })
```

[Here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) you have more information.

Comment: where do I set options.resumable to false? I never set it to true myself.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the limit in firebase storage security rules: see [here](https://hackernoon.com/firebase-setup-storage-upload-browser-in-3-step-tutorial-example-bucket-website-javascript-vue-react-driect-4d005c001152)

for example set:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<your-firebase-storage-bucket>/o {
    match /images/{imageId} {
      // Only allow uploads of any image file that's less than 5MB
      allow write: if request.resource.size < 10 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Backend SDKs running in Cloud Functions are going to by pass security rules, so this would have no effect.

Comment: tried adding this part

 match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.resource.size < 15 * 1024 * 1024
    }

still getting the same error from the logs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as yours, ie .config is not writtable, I created a folder named .config in the root and it worked for me

```
mkdir .config
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the firebase admin API to upload to storage as follows:

```
await bucket.upload(filePath, { destination, resumable: false })
```

This was imposing a file size limit. Not sure what the limit is but a 45MB video file was OK. 250MB video file was NOT OK. This hints at a variable limit according to bandwidth and so on:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads#size

I removed the file size limit as follows:

```
await bucket.upload(filePath, { destination, resumable: true })
```